# Using awk to find a string in a file

Tags: shell

So I want to grab a string from a file, file contains data:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Id   Name      CreationDate         Comment
----------------------------------------------------
1    testing    19.10.11             created by jag

2    develop    19.10.12             created by jag

3    array      19.10.12             created by jaguuuu

4    start123   19.10.12             created by akj
```

I want to grep both start123 but using only start because following number changes from time to time. So it could be start456, start567. But it will start with start****.

This is what I tried so far:

```
awk '$0 ~ arr{print NR-1 FS b}{b=$0}' arr="start" /filepath
echo "string found : $arr"
```

Updating:
Also I want to extract only start123 from second column which could be in any row from 1-4 or 1-whatever number. Once I got the string "start123", want to store it in an variable.
Sorry for not being clear initially.

So if I try to sort it via comment = created by akj and print out start123 still. I think it will be just an && statement. 
Will something like this work:

```
arr=$(awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2 }' /filepath)
 if [ -z "$arr" ]
 then echo "string not found"
 else echo "String found: $arr"
 fi
```

It is not working for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Kyle

Comment: "grep" is the name of a program that will do what you want.  Is there a reason you are using awk? (which will also do what you want, but it's not as easy as using grep)

Comment: The example that I referred was using awk, so I have being trying to get this to work. But I don't know what I am doing wrong. I want to know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-o` option of `grep` to print just the part of the file that matches the regular expression. In this case, it's `start` followed by any number of digits.

```
str=start
if arr=$(grep -o "$str[0-9]*" /filepath)
then echo "string found: $arr"
else echo "string not found"
fi
```

If you only want to find it in column 2, you can use awk:

```
arr=$(awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }' /filepath)
if [ -z "$arr" ]
then echo "string not found"
else echo "String found: $arr"
fi
```

Comment: I want to print start123 and store that in a variable.

Comment: Maybe you should say something like that in the question? There's nothing about printing just the second column or assigning to a variable in there.

Comment: actually my bad again. As I mentioned in the code there could be string such as start123, start456, Can I sort it via comment?

I tried as I updated the code. Also once found should stop, It just continues to run. Wonder why???

Comment: I tried my code and it worked. It matches `start` followed by any sequence of digits.

Comment: yes, it prints everything that contains start***. I am trying to tweak it where lets say it has start123, start456, start566. Once it hits the first one. for example: start123. it should store it in an variable and stop from going to other one.

Comment: OK, I added an `exit` statement so it stops after the first match.

Comment: Thank you. New to regular expressions, Will have to read more. Thanks you again Sir.

Comment: can we also have the output in an variable and instead of file path use the varible??
which according to me, will be just a = "/home/eripflo/text.file" or a = print"A"

Comment: also what does -z "arr" means ---> does it mean if it is equal to arr?

Comment: If _what_ is equal to `arr`? It tests whether `$arr` is empty. Is `man test` broken on your system?

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk:

```
gawk 'match($0, /(start[0-9]+)/, m) {print m[1]; exit}'
```

documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions

Comment: Instead of file path can I have variable??
arr=$(awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }' /filepath)

Comment: sure: `gawk -v str=start 'match($0, "(" str "[0-9]+", m) {print m[1]; exit}' /filepath`