# In shell for awk, can I have variable instead of file path?

Tags: shell

For awk,

Instead of file path can I have variable??
     
     `arr=$(awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }' /filepath)`

Note output was in file path before and now It is in an variable "A".
Tried the following:

```
  arr=$(awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }' ,$a)
arr=$(awk -v VAR="a" str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }' ,$a)
```

Doesn't work.

Previous post for more details:
Visit [Using awk to find a string in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753410/using-awk-to-find-a-string-in-a-file/25755460#25755460)!

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Use: `arr=$(echo "$a" | awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }')`

Comment: sorry let me try again.. will update it soon..

Comment: so you have shell code that says (something like) `a-/filepath` ? Maybe you need `export a=/filepath`. AND recall that all text, including variable names in Linux/Unix are case-sensitive. `$a` and `$A` are two different variables. You have been warned! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: arg, why did you add a comma before `$a`? That can't help. In you 2nd `arr=`, you're using `-v VAR` which would be an awk internal variable, but you never reference `VAR` inside of awk.  The variable `$a` is visible only in the shell, not to awk. If you have `a=/filepath`, then you cmd is trying to execute `awk ... ,/filepath`. Note the problematic comma!  Get one of your `awk` lines to output the data you need without wrapping it in `arr=$(..)`. Once that is working, then add the `arr=$(...)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This worked, thanks anubhava

Use:

```
arr=$(echo "$a" | awk -v str=start '$2 ~ "^" str "[0-9]*" { print $2; exit; }')
```